# Angled CSS background with bottom border.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS background that looks like this:

[image]

I've been able to create the shape, but can't figure out how to add the bottom border, and am starting to think my approach may be the problem.

So far I have the following CSS:

```
#top-background-flag {
  border-top: 2px solid #C2C2C2;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom right,
    #5DCAD3 50%,
    transparent 50.5%
  )
  no-repeat bottom, /* bottom part */
  linear-gradient(100deg, #5DCAD3, #5DCAD3) no-repeat top;
  /* top portion */
  padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C2C2C2;
  background-size: 100% 3rem, 100% calc(100% - 3rem)
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id=top-background-flag>
  A fun title
</div>
```

and a code pen: https://codepen.io/arel/pen/PKXGmd

My problem right now is that the bottom border is a horizontal line, and I can't figure out how to have it follow the angle of the box.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Dekel. didn't notice yours came first. Just gave you the checkmark.

Comment: he commented here to ask for credit and then he deleted the requesting comment...  you decide for yourself what that means

Comment: @McHat I simply asked why the accepted answer is the one that was copied from my answer. Indeed it's the decision of the OP to choose which answer he likes, I just wanted to know why he decided to choose the answer that was copied from mine. Thats all.

Comment: @dekel I did not copy from your answer.  You are not the only one with skill in CSS.  Your answer was an elegant(and obvious) one, and one I personally endorse--because my recommendation is the same.  I took the time to provide a codepen.  Perhaps this is the reason that my response took several minutes longer than yours.

Comment: I like that OP gave it to guy three though.  Perfect, really, given SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to use a linear gradient may not be the best solution here.

Appending an object with a little CSS transformation some judicious layering will accomplish what you want and will have fewer properties to adjust if you want to change the angle later.

```
#top-background-flag {
  border-top: 2px solid #C2C2C2; /* top border on the parent */
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top-background-flag:before {
  background-color: #5DCAD3;
  transform: skewy(-4deg); /* angle you want */
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C2C2C2; /* bottom border skews with the object */
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prqNee) to play with

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to fake a bottom border:

```
#top-background-flag:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 23px;
  transform: rotate(-5.5deg);
}
```

Here is a working fork of your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaojPp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for, but you can use the `:after` pseudo class with the `content` trick:

```css
body {
  max-width: 500px;
}

#top-background-flag {
  border-top: 2px solid #C2C2C2;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom right,
    #5DCAD3 50%,
    transparent 50.5%
  )
  no-repeat bottom, /* bottom part */
  linear-gradient(100deg, #5DCAD3, #5DCAD3) no-repeat top;
  /* top portion */
  padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C2C2C2;
  background-size: 100% 3rem, 100% calc(100% - 3rem);
  position: relative;
}

#top-background-flag:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 22px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-5.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div id=top-background-flag>
  A fun title
</div>
```